# Telethon: autoreply to Telegram stopped working. How to fix?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I am using the following tutorial: https://medium.com/@jiayu./automatic-replies-for-telegram-85075f28321

Thus, my code is:

```py
import time

from telethon import TelegramClient, events

# sample API_ID from https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/f98fdeab3fb2ba6f55daf8481595f879729d1b84/Telegram/SourceFiles/config.h#L220
# or use your own
api_id = XXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXX'

# fill in your own details here
phone = 'XXXXX'
session_file = '/path/to/session/file'  # use your username if unsure
password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'  # if you have two-step verification enabled

# content of the automatic reply
message = "This message is autogenerated.\nApologies, I am unavailable at the moment. Feel free to call me for anything urgent."

count = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the client and connect
    # use sequential_updates=True to respond to messages one at a time
    client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash, sequential_updates=True)


    @client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
    async def handle_new_message(event):
        if event.is_private:  # only auto-reply to private chats
            from_ = await event.client.get_entity(event.from_id)  # this lookup will be cached by telethon
            if not from_.bot:  # don't auto-reply to bots
                print(count, time.asctime(), '-', event.message)  # optionally log time and message
                # print(  '-', time.asctime())  # optionally log time and message
                count += 1 # incrementing the count
                time.sleep(1)  # pause for 1 second to rate-limit automatic replies
                await event.respond(message)


    print(time.asctime(), '-', 'Auto-replying...')
    client.start(phone, password)
    client.run_until_disconnected()
    print(time.asctime(), '-', 'Stopped!')
```

The code worked perfectly the first time I ran it. Then I stopped it, changed the message and it doesn't work anymore. It is launching with the message "Auto-reply..." but does not reply to messages on Telegram. Restarting the computer or removing the session file did not help.

Is it something to do with Telegram blocking the connection?

EDIT: Sometimes it works and works perfectly. Sometimes it won't work at all :(

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Stopped working" is quite vague. Does it just refuse to start? Does it report any error message? Didnt you upgrade your dependencies or something?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko, sure! Sorry:)

There are no errors, it starts and seems to be working with no errors. However, it does not create an automatic response. Sometimes it does (one day), and the other it doesn't. I've discovered this is a common issue https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1541, I just need time to fix it. I will come back to this post with a solution once I find one.

PS The dependencies and packages are of the correct versions. I am using Conda for this.

Comment: @DaniilGannota Have you solved this issue yet? Can you share for this?

Comment: @AJHope, sorry, but no  I found further proof that it doesn’t work because the library needed an update but it was not maintained, so I just gave up. If you found a solution by now, feel free to share!

Comment: @DaniilGannota I solved the issue. Change parameter sequential_updates=False.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **from_** with **sender_** everywhere in the code i.e. 3 times.

> Breaking Changes
>
> > Message.from_id is now a Peer, not int! If you want the marked sender ID (much like old behaviour), replace all uses of .from_id with .sender_id. This will mostly work, but of course in old and new versions you have to account for the fact that this sender may no longer be a user.
> > https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/misc/changelog.html?highlight=from_id#id14